# работа с большими целыми числами в Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, int

буду признателен если подскажете есть ли способ работы с очень большими целыми числами в Pandas.

например, тип данных int64 это числа в диапазоне от -9223372036854775808 по 9223372036854775807, и если результат вычислений - это число не из этого диапазона, то получаем не совсем то что ожидалось:

```
79**10  
>>>
9468276082626847201

pd.Series([78,79])**10
>>>
0    8335775831236199424
1   -8978467991082704415
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В вашем конкретном случае это решается заданием беззнакового типа `uint64`, а вот если и его не хватит, или у вас возможны и отрицательные числа, то будет сложнее, поскольку целых типов длины 128 в `Pandas`/`Numpy` уже нет.

```
pd.Series([78,79], dtype='uint64')**10
```

Вывод:

```
0    8335775831236199424
1    9468276082626847201
dtype: uint64
```

А если взять `float128`, то там другая проблема будет - в последних знаках будут уже цифры не те, если повышать степень. В общем, `Pandas`/`Numpy` под такое не очень заточены.

P.S. Можно и `Decimal` запихать в `pandas.Series`, но он будет лежать там как `object` и эффективность будет страдать. Но работать такое будет до бОльших степеней. А если точность у `Decimal` выставить побольше, то и ещё больших степеней можно достигнуть:

```
from decimal import Decimal

series = pd.Series(map(Decimal, [78,79]))
print(series**14)
```

Вывод:

```
0    308549209196654470906527744
1    368790120348678391253573281
dtype: object
```

P.P.S. Да собственно я торможу, никто не мешает и `int` запихать как `object`:

```
series = pd.Series([78,79], dtype='object')
print(series**25)
```

Вывод:

```
0    200615769179944123990033289551061546247879917568
1    275852727404510985186163978883510976421015681999
dtype: object
```

Comment: спасибо. это выход!